# Haskell list of lists

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

say I have a list in haskell [2,4,6,8,9,4] , and I want to start on the first element and then jump by one or two elements and get all possible combinations.so I should get a list of lists.
so for the above list I want to return the following list [[2,6,9],[2,6,4],[2,8,4]].
I wrote this so far

```
paths :: [int] -> [int]
paths [] = []
paths [x]=[x]
paths (x:z:xs) = x:paths(xs)
```

but it only returns one list starting at the first element and then jumping by ones. So I dont know how to make it recurse so that it jumps twos and ones for all possible jumps .

Help is highly appreciated .

Comment: Note that `int` matches any type (which is okay in this case) since it starts with a lowercase letter. The basic word-size integer type is `Int`. Anything in a type signature that starts with a lowercase letter is a type variable.

Comment: You could start with a function that actually returns a list of lists. The type should be `[a] -> [[a]]`.

Comment: Is `[2,8]` part of the output for that input? If it isn't, why not?

Comment: yes carl it shoud be , sorry I forgot it , I really have been trying to solve this for a day now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to jump over either one or two elements. Therefore, you need not only one, but two recursive calls (if you want to solve this problem with a recursive strategy).

But first of all, lets fix your type:

```
paths :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

Also, I'm going to change the base case: if the input is empty, the result isn't an empty list, but instead a list containing an empty list, since there is only one combination over the empty set, and that is an empty set again. Also, for the singleton, we're going to return a packed singleton list:

```
paths []  = [[]]
paths [x] = [[x]]
```

Now what if we have more elements? We remember first one, jump over one or two, and then apply `paths` again on the rest. However, we only jump two if there's actually something to jump over. Afterwards, we put the first element back at the front:

```
paths (x:xs)
 | null jump1 = [[x]]
 | otherwise  = map (x:) $ paths jump1 ++ paths jump2
 where jump1 = drop 1 xs
       jump2 = drop 2 xs
```

Example:

```
\> paths [2,4,6,8,9,4]
[[2,6,9],[2,6,4],[2,8,4],[2,8]]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for , you are a a life saver Zeta, thanks soooo much :)

Comment: I strongly recommend against writing this function using `length`. It makes it run significantly slower. Also, with some minor tweaking, the algorithm could be made to work on infinite lists, so long as it doesn't use `length`.

Comment: For the curious, that minor tweak is is replacing `++` with interleaving the two subpath results together.